# Forcing GNU make to run commands in order

Tags: make, parallelism

With the following Makefile, GNU make runs the two commands in parallel. Since the first one takes time to finish, `rm *.log` is run before the `log` file is created, and fails.

```
dummy.pdf: dummy.tex
    tex dummy.tex &> /dev/null;
    rm *.log
```

The file `dummy.tex` one line: `\bye` (a short empty file for TeX). Replacing `tex dummy.tex` by any other command shows the same behaviour. Removing `&> /dev/null` would of course solve the problem, but it is not a very good option in my case, since the Makefile is provided by a third party.

Is it possible to prevent GNU make from doing anything in parallel? (the flag `-j 1` does not help).

EDIT: output to the terminal:

```
bruno@bruno-laptop:~/LaTeX/make-experiment$ make
tex dummy.tex &> /dev/null;
rm *.log
rm: cannot remove `*.log': No such file or directory
make: *** [dummy.pdf] Error 1
bruno@bruno-laptop:~/LaTeX/make-experiment$ This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
(./dummy.tex )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on dummy.log.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, you don't have a problem with make, but with your command:

```
tex dummy.tex &> /dev/null;
```

Runs 'tex' in the background. You don't need to remove '>/dev/null', but '&' is sending 'tex' to the background.

Try this, it must be fine for you:

```
tex dummy.tex > /dev/null;
```

or run everything in the same subshell, like this:

```
(tex dummy.tex > /dev/null;rm *.log)
```

or less sane, this:

```
if test 1 = 1; then tex dummy.tex > /dev/null;rm *.log; fi
```

PD: &> is an extension provided by some shells (including bash) to redirect both stdout and stderr to the same destination, but it's not portable, you should use '>/dev/null 2>&1' instead. (Thanks @Gilles)

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. That seems reasonable. Is it possible to avoid changing the Makefile? (I doubt it) I'll ask the maintainers of the Makefile why they did it that way and report back here.

Comment: @Bruno: `&>` is an extension provided by some shells (including bash) to redirect both stdout and stderr to the same destination, but it's not portable. It's likely that the author of the Makefile has bash as his `/bin/sh`, but you have ash or ksh which doesn't support this syntax.

Comment: @Gilles: `<noob question>` how do I know what shell I'm using? And is there a protable alternative?

Comment: Yes, but then, you should use '>/dev/null 2>&1' instead

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Check if `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link. Note that `/bin/sh` may not be the shell you're using interactively. Instead of `mycommand &>dest` (csh/bash/zsh-specific), you can write `mycommand >dest 2>&1`, which is portable to any shell that make might use.

Comment: @D4RIO: I'll propose that to the package maintainer. By the way, `echo $SHELL` yields `/bin/bash`, and `bash --version` gives `4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: @Gilles: `/bin/bash` is not a symbolic link. So it's kind of odd that `&>` doesn't work. But I'll live with that unknown: the maintainer is happy to change to the more canonical form `> /dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: AFAIK $SHELL is your user shell as defined in /etc/passwd, but makefile will try to use /bin/sh.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Not `/bin/bash`, but `/bin/sh`. See if it's a symbolic link or a hard link, to `/bin/ash`, maybe. The easiest way to see this is `ls -l /bin/*sh`.

Comment: @Gilles: I tried to be clever, thinking "my $SHELL is `bash`", but well. Indeed, `\bin\sh` is a symlink to `\bin\dash`. Mystery (essentially) solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: @D4RIO: perhaps add the `> /dev/null 2>&1` version to your answer to make it complete?

Comment: Hmm.. dash is a minimal shell. Good for the root restoring a system, but the hell for average users. If it's your system, make /bin/dash the root's shell (/etc/passwd), but link /bin/sh to bash or ksh or something like that, so your /bin/sh is a sane shell.

Comment: The semi-"standard" way to redirect both standard out and standard error is `>&`, not `&>`.  Bash and zsh support both.  The various csh descendants only support the first.  The nice thing about the first form is that on shells that don't support it, it is more likely to error, rather than run the command in the background.

Answer (score 2):

Er?  `make` parallelizes targets (with `-j`); it never reorders commands within a target.

Comment: I would agree... But it does `:-s`.

Comment: Your comment just saved the day. I had saved `-j8` as a global value for MAKEFLAGS and was wondering why everything was not being executed in order!!